# put an already teetering state on the canvas

Tags: meaning

The fact that a swathe of Persian nobles fell in the course of the battle heavily compromised future resistance, and served to put an already teetering state on the canvas.(The Silk Roads)

What is the meaning of this : put a teetering state on the canvas ?

Does it mean break down, or collapse?

Comment: Careful! You missed "to put" from your quote!

Answer (score 2):

To put someone or something on the canvas is an expression from the boxing world. The floor of a boxing ring is covered in canvas. And when a boxer is knocked out or knocked down, s/he falls to the canvas floor or, is put on the canvas. Unless that boxer regains his (her - these days) feet within a count of ten, the match is over.

Answer (score 2):

"Put (something) on the canvas" is a metaphor from boxing.  The floor of a boxing or wrestling ring is covered in canvas.

So to "put someone on the canvas" means to knock them down in a boxing match If you are "on the canvas" for more than a count of 10, you lose the match:

> Tyson finished round two with a whirlwind of punches that put his opponent on the canvas.

So figuratively it means that Persia was either defeated, or was close to being defeated after this battle.